# Expanding nested macro calls during code compilation/evaluation

Tags: common-lisp

I have a next piece of code:

```
(in-package :cl-user)

(defmacro test0 (form)
  (format t "test0: Expander phase: ~s" form)
  `(format t "test0: Expansion phase: ~s" ,form))

(defmacro test1 (form)
  (format t "test1: Expander phase: ~s" form)
  (test0 form)
  `(format t "test1: Expansion phase: ~s" ,form))
```

Common Lisp implementation: `"SBCL 1.3.16"`.

1. Results of `(compile-file "source.lisp")`:

   `; compiling (IN-PACKAGE :CL-USER)
   ; compiling (DEFMACRO TEST0 ...)
   ; compiling (DEFMACRO TEST1 ...)test0: Expander phase: FORMtest0: Expander phase: FORM`
2. Results of `(load "source.lisp")`:

   `; #<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER">
   ; TEST0
   test0: Expander phase: FORM
   ; TEST1`

And I just can't understand next things:

1. Why is nested subform `(test0 form)` expanded and processed in the definition of `test1` macro? Why isn't it processed in the macro call instead?
2. Where is Common Lisp standard specify such a behavior? `eval-when`? Files compilation? Forms evaluation?
3. Finally, why is `"test0: Expander phase: FORM"` printed twice during compilation(`compile-file`) and only once during evaluation(`load`)?

I think the answers are pretty obvious but I can't find them out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *macro* is a function which operates on *code*.
Since in Lisp *code* is just a
[`list`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_list.htm), 
[macro functions](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_m.htm#macro_function) look like ordinary functions.

Your `defmacro test1` is treated as a definition of a *function*, so all the code is processed appropriately and `(test0 form)` is macroexpanded when the SBCL compiles `defmacro test1`. This answers q1.

[`load`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_load.htm) "sequentially executes
each form it encounters", so to answer your q2, you need to read [3.1
Evaluation](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_a.htm), specifically,
[3.1.2.1.2.2 Macro Forms](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_ababb.htm).

As for how many times a macro is expanded, this is not specified by the
standard (an implementation can expand it on every call of the user
function!), and this is a reason why it is not a good idea for a macro
to have side effects (e.g., to do output).
In your case, loading requires expansion when `test1` is defined.
Compilation expands when it defines `test1` and then again when it
compiles it.
Remember, `defmacro` arranges that the macro can be used in the
following code (including in itself recursively), so is has to be defined immediately.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it helps me a lot. But some points are still unclear to me.
"sequentially executes each form it encounters" - for macro form it means "expand and evaluate result".
But how is function forms executed? 
I mean, the function evaluate subforms(body) when it's called. But what is done during `load` or `compile-file`? 
As I understand, compiler can optimize calls somehow, for example, inline function.
But where is specified in the standard how function forms is executed?

Comment: I suggest that you ask a separate question about "top level forms". Comments is not the right place for new questions.